# Having trouble getting update in Laravel to work

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel

I am currently working on a project for University. I'm trying to get an update function to work. I have shown my code below any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

I have the view file showing whats currently in the database, I want to edit one field and update this back to the database.

Thanks in advance.

Controller

```
        <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;


    use Auth;


    class LessonsController extends Controller


    {

    public function update(Request $request) 

        {
            $lesson->level = $request->level;
            $lesson->update();

            return redirect('./lessons/');
        }

    }
```

view file

```
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>


    <form  class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="./{{ $lesson->id }}"> 
                    {{ method_field('put') }}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="level" class="form-control" value="{{ $lesson->level }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                        <input type="submit" id="update-account" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
                    </div>
                    </div>

                </form>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ID(primary key) to update the data

```
public function update(Request $request) 
    {
        $lesson = Lesson::find($id);
        $lesson->level = $request->level;
        $lesson->save();

        return redirect('./lessons/');
    }
```

I think if you only want to update the level.. better to use `PATCH` method..

I think that `put` method is using when you want to update all table data, but `patch` method is using to update not all parameter of your model #CMIIW

Comment: yes using patch worked but again another error this time it is SQL SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`b00657229`.`lessons`, CONSTRAINT `lessons_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`level`) REFERENCES `users` (`level`)) (SQL: update `lessons` set `level` = begin, `updated_at` = 2018-05-03 06:52:51 where `id` = 13)

Comment: Got it working there figured out I had to either enter beginner intermediate or advanced

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a hidden input field for keep lesson id

`<input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $lesson->id }}" />`

2. There is many ways to get request fields in controller. You can use `$request->get('key')`

And then :

```
$lesson = Lesson::where('id', $request->get('id'))->firstOrFail();
$lesson->level = $request->get('level');
$lesson->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i get another error now - Class 'Lessons' not found

Comment: add `use App\Lesson;` at the top of your controller @NiamhFlannery

Comment: Hi thanks I tried this but get an SQL error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`b00657229`.`lessons`, CONSTRAINT `lessons_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`level`) REFERENCES `users` (`level`)) (SQL: update `lessons` set `level` = begin, `updated_at` = 2018-05-03 06:52:51 where `id` = 13)

Comment: Got it working there figured out I had to either enter beginner intermediate or advanced

Answer (score 1):

Include the `Lesson` model namespace at the top of your file:

```
use App\Lesson;
// or App\Models\Lesson if you placed it under a different directory, for example.
```

You can simplify the query to find the `Lesson` record by using route model binding:

```
public function update(Request $request, Lesson $lesson) 
{
    $lesson->update([
        'level' => $request->level
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('lessons.show', compact('lesson'));
}
```

Update the form action, as well:

```
action="{{ route('lessons.update', $lesson->id) }}"
```

Comment: Hi I get an SQL error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`b00657229`.`lessons`, CONSTRAINT `lessons_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`level`) REFERENCES `users` (`level`)) (SQL: update `lessons` set `level` = begin, `updated_at` = 2018-05-03 06:52:51 where `id` = 13)

Comment: Got it working there figured out I had to either enter beginner intermediate or advanced